# simple regular expression on python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, io

I'm using python 2.X and I'm loading a text from a file, and here is one line from the text

> Odio ¿Mañana pensar porque RT luego pasa lo que pasa Marzo ♡♡♡

I found this regular expression [^\x30-\xFF] to match exactly the characters I wanted (using online regex tools), but when I use it in my code like this:

```
filtered_comments = re.sub("[^\x30-\xFF]", " ", all_comments)
```

it doesn't match the same characters; you may try that on http://pythex.org
so in this text I want to match  ♡♡♡ and leave ñ and ¿
.... any idea?

Comment: because I'm actually not interested just in this line, I have a class of non-ASCII characters in the text in the file I'm working with which I need to capture but not all non-ASCII like ñ

Answer (score 2):

Try following script, Please see `#coding=utf-8` on first line. For more information please see [PEP-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

comments = u"Odio ¿Mañana pensar porque RT luego pasa lo que pasa Marzo ♡♡♡"

rx = re.compile(u"[\u2661]+")

# If you want to remove non-ASCII characters, as you mentioned in comments,
# uncomment following regex. 
# Downside is it will remove all accented characters too.
#
# rx = re.compile(u"[^\x00-\x7F]+")

filtered_comments = re.sub(rx, " ", comments)

print filtered_comments
```

It will print

```
Odio ¿Mañana pensar porque RT luego pasa lo que pasa Marzo
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, and got this error message: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: did you added `#coding=utf-8` as first line of your python script?

Comment: copy posted code into new python file and try running it.

Comment: I did copy that line and put it on the very top of the script. OK, so now it's python3, and the problem with this solution is that it is specific to ♡♡♡ when I really want it to work for all non-ASCII characters that look like emoji.

Comment: non-ASCII will remove all accented characters too. e.g. `¿Mañana`, but if you still want to do so, I have updated my regex.

Comment: Mapping against full set of unicode symbol characters in regex is not efficient. These are thousands of characters and still growing.

Comment: please take a look at [this](http://regexr.com/3d0cj) it matches exactly what I want. Great I want to learn more about how these charcter sets "look" like and not just what they refer to like [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) under Unicode Blocks

Comment: Note it didn't match characters like ¿ % ° º which I defiantly want to match since my whole goal is to remove any non ASCII characters but keep accented letters. Let's say that I want only English AND accented letters from other languages and exclude EVERYTHING else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106144/discussion-between-saleem-and-abdulelah-al-jeffery).

Comment: @Saleem your coding header is wrong. it should be literally `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, not sure what do you mean but this header work perfectly fine. see demo https://repl.it/BveP/0

Comment: @Saleem I see Python 3, not Python 2. Python 3 is unicode always

Comment: Yep, I agree with you. But see OP is using Python 2.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, please see our discussion at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106144/discussion-between-saleem-and-abdulelah-al-jeffery. I'm wondering if you have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is `all_comments` of `type` `str` or `unicode`?  If it's of type `unicode` and the characters print properly, your regular expression should work.

If your string is of type `str`, you'll need to encode it using the correct encoding.  Assuming your encoding is UTF-8, this will work:

```
filtered_comments = re.sub("[^\x30-\xFF]", " ", all_comments.decode('utf-8'))
```

Another thing to note: you `^\x30-\xFF` matches `!` and `#` and a number of other symbols which are below `\x30`.  Maybe you want `^\x20-\xFF` because `\x20` is space which is pretty much the lowest typical ASCII character?

Comment: all_comments is of 'str' type and it originally prints all non ASCII characters just fine, without adding "# coding=utf-8" on top or anything. Now when I copy and past your line, I get the following error msg. "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: If it's of `str` type you need to use the `decode` method to get it into a `unicode` format. That error message means that `utf-8` is probably not the right encoding. You need to use the correct encoding. You'll need to look up how to check the character encoding in your text editor or for your operating system and then use that encoding.

Comment: What operating system are you on? I believe the default encoding on Windows is sometimes `utf-16-be`.